# PHP user styling not in line with existing style

Tags: php, html, css

I am using a standard navbar-right for a navbar with bootstrap. Everything is fine until I use PHP for the username and it becomes out of line.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>      
</ul>
```

The above is my current code and the PHP ends up above the Sign Up text. 
Is it possible to fix this with CSS? [The problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZI6R.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like below:-

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){?>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></li>
    <?php }else{?>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    <?php}?>
</ul>
```

Note:- when session have username then why sign-up link there? Isn't it. If yes then  my code will perfectly fine for you

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about just not having the sign up as it is still a WIP site. I had to fix the code by putting endif and using colons instead of {} as it is already inside of an if statement.